How to copy industrial Vanilla Pudding
Im trying to copy instant royal vanilla puddings recipe for my cookies that require it except without the preservatives and food dyes. The instant pudding seems to contain 3 main ingredients, sugar, modified cornstarch and tetrasodium pyrophosphate.
The primary issue is that food grade tetrasodium pyrophosphate is hard to come by, I was wondering if something like xantham, agar or arrowroot would be a suitable substitute?
Lastly if it is a viable substitute what would be the exact amounts of all 3 ingredients?
Sorry for the difficult question, I have searched far and wide for an answer and cant seem to find anything.

Yes, it’s a thickener, but it’s also reported to be used to help with dispersion and an emulsifier. You might be able to replace it with mechanical agitation instead of an ingredient.  (This is an untested assumption; not based on specific experience, which is why I’m not putting it as an answer)

Yeah, the cornstarch is also a thickener and emulsifier, so I would try without the pyrophosphate. As for proportions, I'd look for any generic blancmange (pudding thickened by starch) recipe and experiment a bit.


The primary issue is that food grade tetrasodium pyrophosphate is hard to come by, I was wondering if something like xantham, agar or arrowroot would be a suitable substitute?

In my experience when trying to replicate store bought pudding. The most difficult thing to replicate is the mouth feel. From a quick bit of reading, that appears to be one of the main functions of tetrasodium pyrophosphate when used in food. The fact it's so prominent in the ingredients list would lead you to assume that's its function / effect is pretty important to the product's texture.
I've also found that different types of starches, have pretty different types of mouth feel. Which, along with various "How it's Made" style shows (including a couple in the UK that are dedicated to commercial food production), has lead me to believe that the exact composition and balance between the various starches, emulsifiers, and gelling agents is what gives store bought puddings their distinct textures.

Lastly if it is a viable substitute what would be the exact amounts of all 3 ingredients?

Without an actual recipe or some kind of more detailed ingredients list, there's just no way of answering that question without a lot of trial and error... or some light industrial spying.
Royal's Instant Vanilla Pudding has a total of 18 ingredients listed on the label (assuming that "MONO- AND DIGLYCERIDES" are two ingredients... and they're both emulsifiers by the way). Non of the ingredients have their quantities specified exactly but aside from the first three, the last fifteen ingredients are listed as "CONTAINS 2% OR LESS OF". If you take it to the extreme and assume that they're all 2% of the total recipe. Then that means that "SUGAR, FOOD STARCH MODIFIED, TETRASODIUM PYROPHOSPHATE" make up about 72% of the recipe and that each individual ingredient is more than 2%... that could still mean that the sugar could make up 66% of the recipe. Or it could be as little as 24%. Of course, that's assuming that 28% of the recipe is accounted for by the last fifteen ingredients. It could still be much greater than 66%.
As someone who has tried to replicate similar products in the past, the best advice I can give you is to focus your research on either similar products, for which you might be able to find a proper, detailed ingredients list. Or you should look into the difference in texture between the various starches, emulsifiers, and gelling agents that you're able to buy.
The other thing I'd say is that I mainly use either cornstarch or potato starch when I cook, and in my experience cornstarch results in a pudding texture that feels fattier and more satisfying on my palate. Whereas potato starches don't feel as rich or fatty on my palate. It's like the difference between skimmed and semi-skimmed milk (0% and 2% milk I believe they call them in the USA). I also like to just use egg yolks, in addition to the cornstarch, to add richness and a custard like smoothness to the pudding.
Xanthan gum can help with giving lower fat recipes, a mouth feel closer to than of higher fat recipes. But you need to use it very precisely and sparingly, and if possible mix it into some oil first before adding it to whatever you're making... and always mix it in thoroughly as soon as you add it. That really helps prevent little balls or "pearls" of unmixed xanthan from forming.
One last note in regards to the tetrasodium pyrophosphate. I have a pH meter that has to be stored in what's called "KCL solution". The ready made solution is expensive to buy but it's just very precise amounts of distilled water and potassium chloride. I found that I had much better success finding cheap potassium chloride powder when I looked at chemical suppliers, rather than food suppliers.

Thanks for your answer, a couple things about what said that I think are relevant is that mouth feel isnt really important in my case because I only need the pudding mix for the cookies.

@JosephPereiro What is it about the dessert that you're trying to replicate then (flavour,  the way it sets etc)?
